# Not able to export the data from hive partitioned table mysql table using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am working on POC where we need to get the data from MySQL Db to Hive partitioned table then need to transfer the data to the table which is MySQL DB.
I have created the table which supports acid properties and partitioned by year and month.
So currently i am not able to transfer the data to MySQL DB.
So can some one suggest me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sqoop import to transfer the table data to hive by below:

```
sqoop import --connect <connection string>
--username <> 
-P  
--table <table name> 
--target-dir <location> <table name> 
--fields-terminated-by "," 
--hive-import 
--create-hive-table 
--hive-table <hive table name
```

Then You can export the data back to my sql using Export in place of import.

```
$ sqoop export \
--connect <connect string>\
--username \
-P
--table <hive table>\ 
--export-dir <location
```

Comment: Hi Subash, above syntax is working for normal table means non partitioned table. i facing problem with partitioned table. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can make use of ----hive-partition-key and --hive-partition-value.Please refer sec 7.2.10 [link] (http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive)